# Format time to minutes and seconds in countdown/timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I am building a pomodoro clock/countdown, but have an issue with formatting selected time to minutes/hours/seconds. I have tried to multiply the secs variable with 60 (secs*=60), but it makes a mess and I can't figure out how to fix it. So, I would like it to "know" that it needs to count down from 25 minutes - in 25:00 format, or more/less(hh:mm:ss) if the user chooses so with + and - buttons. All help very appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="num">25 min</h1>

<div id="status"></div>

<button onclick='countDown(secs, "status")'>Start countdown</button>
<button onclick='increaseNumber()'>+</button>
<button onclick='decreaseNumber()'>-</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is javascript:

```
var num = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
var secs = parseInt(num);

function countDown(secs, elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem); 

    secs--;
      var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    countDown(secs, elem);
    }, 1000);

    //secs *= 60;

     if(secs%60 >= 10){ //10 - if it's not a single digit number
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = (Math.floor(secs/60) + ":" + secs%60);
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = (Math.floor(secs/60) + ":" + "0" + secs%60);
    }

    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" minutes";
    //if timer goes into negative numbers
    if(secs < 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
    }
}

function increaseNumber() {
    secs += 5;
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = secs + ' min';
}

function decreaseNumber() {
    if(secs >= 10) {
        secs -= 5;
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = secs + ' min';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `countDown` function:

```
function countDown(secs, elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" minutes";

    var second = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        var extraZero = second < 10 ? '0' : '';
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = secs + ":" + extraZero + second;

        if (second-- === 0) {
            second = 59;
            if (secs-- === 0){
                clearInterval(timer);
                element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown complete!</h2>';
                element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Since you are counting down the seconds, it is making more sense to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: exactly what I needed, so simple and effective, thank you!

Comment: S could perhaps explain me how exactly  if (second-- === 0) { second = 59; if (secs-- === 0){  part works..? I understand the extraZero part (if second is less than 10 variable extraZero is '0', and if it is bigger it is empty string '') unless I'm getting it wrong. How exactly conditions second-- === 0 and secs-- === 0 work..? In setTimeout I had secs-- which told the function to countDown, how does setInterval "see" it? Thanks once again

Comment: @Joe `setTimeout` only fires once, while `setInterval` fires again and again in intervals. In the `setInterval` function, `second-- === 0` would compare `second` with `0` first, then run `second--` regardless of the comparison result. I set `second` to `0` initially, and do `second--` in every interval. When it reaching `0`, it would be set to `59`. Meanwhile, `secs-- === 0` would run to see how many minutes are left, and do `secs--` regardless of the comparison. Hope that helps!

Comment: I see now, If I got it right there are two intervals going down simultaneously and independent, and second-- actually just goes in circles. Very clever, I learned a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're doing it by hand ?
If you don't mind using a library, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) does a very good job at time manipulations. It's lightweight and very easy to use.

If you have to do it by hand because of some limitations, what are they ?

For reference:

```
//Creates a moment. Its value is the time of creation
var timer = moment();

//add 60 seconds to the timer
timer.add(60, 's');

//Removes 1 minutes from the timer
timer.subtract(1, 'm');
```

Sources :

[Add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

[Substract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it out. I am doing it by hand because I would like to understand the code better, so I was hoping if there is a way to do it